# Зависает PHPStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, webstorm

PHPStorm зависает когда я пытаюсь что то изменить в настройка. Но не всегда, а через раз. А вот когда я когда открываю `Revert Changes` и выбираю любой документ для сравнения, то 100% виснет и притом наглухо! А в остальном работает нормально.
Что я делал:

- переустанавливал сам PHPStorm(пробовал разные версии)
- увеличивал память и проверял настройки
- полностью переустановил apache2,php,git и поставил PHPStorm2019.2EAP

И ничего не помогло...
Что делать? Куда копать?) Переустановка ОС не желательна.
Vm options

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf
-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=10000
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
-Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос был решен полно переустановкой GUI. Вместо Gnome поставил kubuntu plasma.

Answer (score 1):

EAP подразумевает что это тестовая версия, раз у вас такое - оформляйте баг-репорт

Comment: я установил EAP в качестве проверки. Но от этого ничего не меняется...

Comment: @ZIBERMINSK откройте диспетчер задач и посмотрите нагрузку вовремя реверта, скорей всего скорость записи(чтения) у вашего жесткого диска узкое горлышко - ну и оформляйте баг-репорт

Comment: @ZIBERMINSK через консоль реверт проверьте

Comment: К сожалению, такой вариант исключен с SSD Samsung 860 Evo 250GB.
Но я проверял через htop любые изменения, но ничего не получилось выявить ,т.к. по  закрытию формы происходит полное зависание